# How to prevent CocoaPods from removing libraries previously installed

Tags: ios, git, branch, cocoapods

When I run "pod install" CocoaPods removes all the libraries that is not included in the Pod file.

The case where I want these libraries no to be uninstalled is as follow:

I'm working on a project with many branches and each branch have it's own dependencies so a different Pod file, I want to switch between branches and not to "Pod install" every time I switch to a different branch, unless I have a new dependencies.

Comment: you could add Pod folder to the branches... i believe by default it excluded from git commit